# What are the sources and reason for the custom of Blessing Cup (Kos shel Bracha)- drinking a cup of wine after Shabbat morning lunch?

Tags: minhag, grapes-wine

There is a custom that after the end of Birkat Hamazon at Shabbat morning lunch, someone takes cup of wine, bless before Bore Pri Hagefen, and afterwards Me'in Shalosh. What is the origin of this custom? When and at what feasts is it used? Is drinking the wine after the meal considered causing the addition of a blessing that is redundant, because he could drink wine during the meal and be exempt from the blessing in the blessing of the food? Do you practice a cup of blessing also in the singular or only if there are three men (Zimun) or ten?

Comment: In theory, the practice applies at any meal where one says birkat hamazon.

Comment: Just so you know, even if you drink wine during the meal you make a hagafen on it